# I am unable to login

Tags: support, login

I've been trying to log in without success. I requested an account recovery and this is the email I received:

[image: email]

I the email says to log in with stack Exchange option. I clicked on the link and went here:

[image: login screen]

I do not see the Stack Exchange option.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Am I the only one can't see image ?

Comment: @Coffee Probably, I could see it, though going back it directed me to an ad. Very annoying. I'll upload it to imgur

Answer (score 2):

Ooops.
Looks like I was already logged in.
Guess I should grab a cup of coffee.